# Type hinting does not work with a global variable in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, global, type-hinting

Trying to get list methods after `x.` does not work:

```
x = []
def f():
    global x  # type: list
    x.
```

But trying to get list methods after `x.` works without using `global`:

```
x = []
def f():
    x.
```

How do I get hints for globals?

Comment: It seems this is a bug in PyCharm -- see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37755. Not sure if there's a workaround though, sorry. You could maybe try tacking on an `assert isinstance(x, lint)` after the `global x` line to force the type to narrow, or use a [cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) somewhere, but those are both kind of suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the type on the declaration of the variable, not the use. For example:

```py
x: list[str] = []
def f():
    global x
    x.append("some string")
```

When using this method once you type `x.` your IDE should be aware it is a list and will provide `append()` as a function option.

***Note: the `list[str]` syntax is only available since Python 3.9. Prior to this `List` from `typing` must be used. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List for more information***